# Move encryption code from Java to flutter

Tags: java, flutter, dart, encryption

I have mobile android app written with flutter which uses next Java code for encryption:

```
publicKeyBytes = Base64.decode(encodedPublicKey, Base64.URL_SAFE);
KeyFactory factoryKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
X509EncodedKeySpec encodedKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
PublicKey keyPublic = factoryKey.generatePublic(encodedKey);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
OAEPParameterSpec paramSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
cipher.init(1, keyPublic, paramSpec);
byte[] abData = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
return Base64.encodeToString(abData, Base64.URL_SAFE + Base64.NO_WRAP + Base64.NO_PADDING);
```

But now I need to make this code cross platform (iOS, Web). So I'm looking how to move this code to Dart. I tried to use library `pointycastle` but from what I understand they don't support exactly this algorithm. Is it even possible to implement it with Dart right now?

Comment: Pointycastle support RSA with OAEP padding. What do you feel is missing? See: https://github.com/bcgit/pc-dart/blob/master/tutorials/examples/rsa-demo.dart

Comment: When I was looking through pointcastle I found this issue https://github.com/bcgit/pc-dart/issues/86 and assumed I have same case.  And it's not clear for me how to translate this part `X509EncodedKeySpec encodedKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);` to use my public key with pointcastle

Comment: The X509 package should help. https://pub.dev/packages/x509

Comment: did u get answer for about conversion in flutter?